# Django QuerySet in template for relational models

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I am trying to setup a relation with another model using FK in django but I can't call FK related model fields in django templates. In template when I call "provider.name" it shows me "None" as result. I do have 5 different suppliers listed and can see from admin. I have providers and I got products like below:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    sku = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    providers = models.ManyToManyField('Provider', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

   class Provider(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/')
    shipping_method = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    shipping_time = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    return_policy = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    free_delivery = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    customer_service_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    shipping_charges = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

In template the way I am calling it is:

```
{% with provider=object.providers %}
{{ provider.name }}
{% endwith %}
```

As result it shows `"None"`. I am trying to call provider in a different template. In it's own List/Detail generic views it works just fine. I am trying to call it in different app templates. Please advise.

Update................

My search.html for whoosh search engine includes

```
{% for result in page.object_list %}
            <div class="col-lg-1-5  col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="pbox">
              <div class="photo">
                <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ result.object.get_image_url }}" alt="product"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="info">
                <div class="url">
                name
                    {% for item in result.object.providers.all %}
                        {{ result.provider.name }}
                    {% endfor %}

                </div>
                <div class="description">
                  {{ result.object.description|truncatewords:7 }}
                </div>
                <div class="price">
                  {{ result.object.price|intcomma }}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

As I am not using any ModelManager or just using default Managers pre-defined for models. I've added a line of code under Product App model like this:

```
def get_provider(self):
        item = self.providers.all()
        return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I case of calling `provider` you call related manager so it return `None` because manager have no method like this.
If you want to retrieve objects from managers, you should call `self.providers.all()`
In your case, template tags should looks like this:

```
{% for item in object.providers.all %}
    {{ provider.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried this but as I am not using any managers for now so under "Product" app I added a function for get_provider where I simply returned self.providers.all(). I am updating question with my template as well. I am implementing whoosh search engine code so in its search.html you can see how I've listed code.